# Developing an app with an automatically renewable consumable in-app purchase

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, appletv, in-app-purchase

I'm developing a new tvOS app that has in-app purchases. I can't get the in-app purchases to show up in the simulator. What is the proper procedure when introducing in-app purchases to apps that are not yet in the App Store? Should I go ahead and upload a build but **NOT** release it? Will this get the in-app purchases showing in dev so I can continue building the in-app purchase workflow? Or is there another way to get the in-app purchases approved? They are currently in the "Ready to submit" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKProductRequest` only returns the right data when running on a device. My solution was to run my app on an actual Apple TV.